# Incorrect DECIMAL value when inserting MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

The error I'm getting is:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect DECIMAL value: '0' for column '' at row
>   -1

I'm trying to `normalize` a database and ensuring that the data types are correct. Inserting data from `BASE_TABLE` into a new table named `Inventors`.

This is the query I'm using to insert. If I take a single row **manually** from the `select` query it can correctly insert into the Inventors table.

However, running the query like this I instantly get the error above.

```
INSERT INTO
    Inventors(ID,Firstname,Middlename,Lastname,Country,Latitude,Longitude)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Inventor_ID as ID,
    Firstname,
    Middlename,
    Lastname,
    Country,
    cast(Latitude as decimal(11,6)) as Latitude,
    cast(Longitude as decimal(11,6)) as Longitude
FROM
    BASE_TABLE
```

Here is the row which fails to insert in the `select` query:

```
ID          Firstname   Middlename  Lastname    Country     Latitude    Longitude
04308666-3  RICHARD     RICHARD     JUNG                    0.000000    0.000000
```

`Inventors` create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `Inventors` (
  `ID` varchar(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`BASE_TABLE` create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `BASE_TABLE` (
  `Firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zipcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvSeq` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Patent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppYear` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApplyYear` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PubYear` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `AppDate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Assignee` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AsgNum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Coauthor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Invnum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Invnum_N` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Record_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Inventor_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Match_Level` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Classification` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Citing` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cited` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Record_ID`),
  KEY `Inventor_ID` (`Inventor_ID`),
  KEY `Patent` (`Patent`),
  KEY `Patent_2` (`Patent`,`Inventor_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Clearly the `cast()` is not working.  You need to look at the values in those columns.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited post. I added three values from the `select` query.

Comment: . . It only takes one value to fail for you to get that error.

Comment: look if field Longitude  is set unsigned in the destination table

Comment: ...and please, try always to post CREATE TABLE and INSERT script to make easier to help you.

Comment: @BerndBuffen no, it's set as signed. Tried with both without any success.

Comment: If "Latitude" and "Longitude" have to do with "Country", then you still have a transitive dependency. That is, you're not in 3NF. This has more to do with how the question is tagged ( [tag:database-normalization] ) than with the question itself.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' partly, but the lat,lon is not connected to the country. The lat,lon refers to a city or point within the country. But country is just a two letter code. Thanks for the heads up though! I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. `Latitude (VARCHAR)` and `Longitude (VARCHAR)` in `BASE_TABLE` had the value of an empty string `''`. This caused MySQL to cast to an incorrect value for some reason.

I solved this by replacing the empty string with `NULL` in the select query (See below).

```
INSERT INTO
    Inventors
SELECT DISTINCT
    Inventor_ID as ID,
    Firstname,
    Middlename,
    Lastname,
    Country,
    IF(Latitude='',NULL,CAST(Latitude as decimal(11,6))) as Latitude,
    IF(Longitude='',NULL,CAST(Longitude as decimal(11,6))) as Longitude
FROM
    BASE_TABLE
```

Comment: "For some reason"? What decimal numeral is ''?

Comment: Yes @philipxy, for some reason as the cast function returns 0.000000 and not an empty string when receiving an empty string. But it can yet not save it for some reason although 0.000000 is a decimal, I'd presume.

Comment: Why would cast return an empty string when given one? The [spec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) says to pass a string that is an expression of the indicated type. The empty string is not a numeric expression. So you are getting an error.

Comment: Fair enough. Just find it strange that when running the `select` query exclusively, the cast function does not fail when receiving an empty string and instead returns a value of `0.000000`. Not failing during a `select` query but actually failing when running it along an `insert` query makes it quite ambiguous imo.

Comment: You haven't shown what you mean by "take a single row manually from the select query" and "when receiving an empty string and instead returns a value of 0.000000" or why you think it "does not fail".

Answer (score 1):

I would have added this as a comment but don't have the required rep, so my apologies for that.

I ran into the exact same issue and behavior that Philip did.

To answer philipxy's (now 1.75 year old) question, Philip means that:

1. When the SELECT statement is executed *by itself*, it works without any errors - the CAST **succeeds** in turning an empty string ('') into 0.000000 and that is reflected in the query result set.
2. When the SELECT statement is executed *as part of an encompassing INSERT INTO statement*, CAST **fails** to turn that exact same empty string into a decimal value and Error 1366 occurs.

This is what he correctly calls "ambiguous" because the CAST is working differently in those two different use cases, which is confusing at best.  It's also odd that the error message doesn't include a column name and that the row is listed as -1.

I think there might be a bug to be addressed here because CAST should work the same way no matter the scenario.

Luckily, Philip's own Answer also worked for me, so thanks, Philip!