# MySQL Insert incorrect decimal value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO DUMP (storename,
                  balance,
                  otherbalance)
SELECT storename,
       IF(balance = '', 0.0, CAST(balance AS DECIMAL (9,2))) AS balance,
       IF(otherbalance = '', 0, CAST(otherbalance AS DECIMAL(9,2))) AS otherbalance
FROM superchart
AND storename IN ('Superstore')
```

I keep getting:

```
Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1
```

So i looked at:
[Incorrect DECIMAL value when inserting MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140136/incorrect-decimal-value-when-inserting-mysql)

And tried the if '', NULL - same results.

I then did if '', 0.0 - same results

I just don't see how else i can pin point what exactly is bad...i know it is something in the 'otherbalance' column because if I do:

```
INSERT INTO DUMP (storename,
                  balance,
                  otherbalance)
SELECT storename,
       IF(balance = '', 0.0, CAST(balance AS DECIMAL (9,2))) AS balance,
       '0.0' AS otherbalance
FROM superchart
AND storename IN ('Superstore')
```

It actually works, I just don't know how to pint point the record that is bad.

Any body have any suggestions other than the IF = '', NULL...not entirely sure what to try next.

So, I've pin pointed the record, by breaking it down.

So i have two records one that inserts and another that doesn't...if I do a

LENGTH(otherbalance) for both records I get back 4 and the value in the cell is 0.00 so it seems they are casting the same is there any tips/tricks to pull the exact value of the cell before any casting is done?

Thanks,

Comment: What are the datatypes of `balance` and `otherbalance`?

Comment: `FROM 
superchart
AND company` is not valid SQL.  Your code should fail with a compiler error.

Comment: The datatype is TEXT

Comment: Can you post the datatypes and sample data of `balance` and `otherbalance` columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right sorry, i fixed it...it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to have a problem with `balance` not being able to be converted.

If you want the value to be zero in that case, you can simply do:

```
SELECT storename, balance+0
```

This does implicit conversion and doesn't return an error.  Otherwise, use a regular expression to find the offending values.  Something like this:

```
SELECT balance
FROM superchart
WHERE balance not regexp '^[-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0.9]*$';
```

This should return the offending values.